# Replacing multiple row values within each column with N/A

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the first 5 values within each column of my dataframe with `N/A`. However, the dataframe is shaped such that the first 5 values are in differing rows in each column. I have tried using the `replace_with_na` function of `nanier` library, but I haven't been able to correctly index each row within each column

My dataframe looks like (my values are not actually sequential):

```
    col1   col2   col3
     N/A    1     N/A
     N/A    2      1
      1     3      2
      2     4      3
      3     5      4 
      4     6      5 
      5     7      6
```

I would like the resulting dataframe to look like:

```
    col1   col2   col3
     N/A    N/A    N/A
     N/A    N/A    N/A
     N/A    N/A    N/A
     N/A    N/A    N/A
     N/A    N/A    N/A 
     N/A    6      N/A
     N/A    7      6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check if lag 5 is na.

**Code**

```
library(hablar)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(~if_else_(!is.na(lag(., 5)), ., NA))
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
   col1  col2  col3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA    NA
2    NA    NA    NA
3    NA    NA    NA
4    NA    NA    NA
5    NA    NA    NA
6    NA     6    NA
7    NA     7     6
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), col2 = c(1, 2, 
                                                         3, 4, 5, 6, 7), col3 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!